# Слетает верстка при нажатии на якорь

Tags: html, css

Задача: сверстать шаблон, у которого в бэкграунде косые линии + такие же косые границы у шапки и подвала. С задачей вроде справился, но обнаружил баг, что если нажать на якорь (sec1,sec2...), то верстка слетает (Обратите внимание на header и footer до и после клика).

Почему это происходит? И какие есть варианты решения задачи или мб нужен вообще дургой подход?

Как я понял это происходит из-за

```
html{ overflow:auto;} body{ overflow:hidden;}
```

Но без этого я не знаю как "утопить"  нижнюю границу футера.

```css
html{
  overflow:auto;
  padding:0px;
  margin:0px;
}
body{
  padding:0px;
  margin:0px;
  overflow:hidden;
}
header{
  transform: skewY(-2deg);
  margin-top:-50px;
}
footer{
transform: skewY(-2deg);
margin-bottom:-50px;
}
header .noshow, footer .show{
  width:100%;
  background: #00f;
  height:100px;
}
header .show, footer .noshow {
  width:100%;
  background: #0f0;
  height:100px;
}
section{
  transform: skewY(-2deg);
  width:100%;
  height:300px;
  background:#f00;
  margin-bottom:20px;
}
nav{
  transform: skewY(-2deg);
  display:flex;
}
nav a{
  margin-left:10px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<header>
<div class="noshow"></div>
<div class="show"></div>
</header>
<nav>
<a href="#sec1">sec1</a>
<a href="#sec2">sec2</a>
<a href="#sec3">sec3</a>
<a href="#sec4">sec4</a>
<a href="#sec5">sec5</a>
</nav>
<main>
<section id="sec1">1</section>
<section id="sec2">2</section>
<section id="sec3">3</section>
<section id="sec4">4</section>
<section id="sec5">5</section>
</main>
<footer>
<div class="noshow"></div>
<div class="show"></div>
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: а что значит - `слетает` ? по клацал я на все ссылки и посмотрел на эффект после этого - не увидел ни чего

Comment: @MaximLensky обратите внимание как выглядит шапка и подвал до клика и после. Я специально сделал их двух цветов. Весь сайт как бы "поднимается". Поэтому у шапки становится не видно синий цвет, а у подвала синей части становится слишком много + появляется просвет в самом низу.

Comment: Уберите у body overflow:hidden, а футеру лучше задайте фиксированную высоту

Comment: @DaemonHK если убрать overflow:hidden - то неполучится спрятать низ. Если поставить футеру фикс высоту - то проблема с адаптивностью, так как футер должен быть на всю ширину экрана, а значит не известна итоговая высота изза наклона. 
На текущий момент так и сделал - но футер вышел 600 пикселе (чтобы с запасом для больших мониторов) й и добавил большой отрицательный  маржин. Но это явный костыль.

Comment: @Pavel для адаптива вы можете менять размеры как захотите)